# Problema al clonar un repositorio de github (java netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, github, aplicación-web

Buen día a todos. En mi trabajo se pidió hacer unos cambios a una página; me pasaron el front, el back y la bd(oracle) de pruebas. El front y la bd funcionan correctamente. El back end es una Web application (java with and) que se conecta a unos web services.

El problema es con el backend, clono el repositorio de github y cuando lo voy a abrir con el netbeans no me aparece para abrir, sólo deja abrir las carpetas, algo que me percate es que no esta la carpeta nbproject. Entonces cree una nueva web application y copie la carpeta nbproject a mi proyecto clonado y de esta forma me dejo abrir el proyecto, sin embargo me da un warning de "Resolve Data Source Problem" agrego la conexión y el driver (odbjc) y al la test de conexión me da exitosa y al darle  finish no da ningun error, sin embargo sigue saliendo el mismo warning.

Otra cosa que me he dado cuenta, con otros proyectos similares que tengo, es que al abrirlos se crean unas carpetas (generated sources) automáticamente (tengo entendido que estas carpetas son generadas por los webservices) pero en mi proyecto no se crean.
Cuando abro el proyecto la carpeta web services referenced donde esta los WS estos me aparecen con una "x" y al darle refresh se quita este "error" ya probé los web services con el soap ui y con otros proyectos y parece que funcionan correctamente.

EL problema es que varios archivos de mi proyecto usan las clases generadas por los WS, al no crear las carpetas (generated sources) obviamente no las encuentra.

Uso netbeans 14 y java 8

Ya no sé que hacer, gracias si alguien me puede colaborar con esto.